# How to display a File[] array in a JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I'm trying to display a list of files that I get of a folder in a JList, this is my code but when I run the project and select the desired folder I obtain the names of the files in the Output console but I can't show that File[] array in the JList.

```
private void jButtonOpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    // Gets the path of the folder selected
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("C:\\...\\ProjectColorCT"));

    int show_fileC = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);

    String pathFolder = null;
    if (show_fileC != JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION ){
        File folderName = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        pathFolder = folderName.getAbsolutePath();
        jTextPathFolder.setText(pathFolder);
    }
    System.out.println(pathFolder);

    // Gets all the names of the files inside the folder selected previously
    File folderCortes = new File(pathFolder);
    File[] archivos = folderCortes.listFiles();
    for (File fichero : archivos) {
        System.out.println(fichero.getName());
    }

    // Create the model for the JList
    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();

    // Add all the elements of the array "archivos" in the model
    for (int i=0 ; i<archivos.length ; i++){
        model.addElement(archivos[i].getName());
    }

    // Add the JList to the JScrollPane
    jCortesList = new JList(model);      
    jScrollCortes = new JScrollPane(jCortesList);

    // Print for testing
    for (int i=0 ; i<archivos.length ; i++){
        jCortesList.setSelectedIndex(i);
        System.out.println(jCortesList.getSelectedValue());
    }     
}
```

I'm adding a `DefaultListModel();` and after I assign that model to the `JList`, finally I assign that `JList` to the `JScrollPane`, but it doesn't show me the list in the interface.

Comment: When does `jScrollCortes` get added to the UI?

Comment: When I add the `JList` from the Swing Controls Palette the `JScrollPane` creates by default and I changed it the name to _jScrollCortes_

Answer (score 0):

Based on your available, out-of-context code, the obvious answer would be, you've not actually added `jScrollCortes` to the UI...

```
private void jButtonOpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    //...    
    // Add the JList to the JScrollPane
    jCortesList = new JList(model);      
    jScrollCortes = new JScrollPane(jCortesList);

    add(jScrollCortes);
    revalidate();
    repaint();
    //...
}
```

This may or may not work depending on how the classes, UI and/or layout is setup.

A better solution would be to have the `JList` and `JScrollPane` already created an displayed on the UI, then all you'd need to do is apply the new `ListModel` to the already existing `JList`

> When I add the JList from the Swing Controls Palette the JScrollPane creates by default and I changed it the name to jScrollCortes

Since you already have an instance of `JList` (wrapped in a `JScrollPane`), then you should simply only need to change the model...

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();

//...

// Add the JList to the JScrollPane
jCortesList.setModel(model);
//jCortesList = new JList(model);      
//jScrollCortes = new JScrollPane(jCortesList);
```

Comment: `jCortesList.setModel(model);`  
woooow! it really works! 
Thank you so much !!!! @MadProgrammer